# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting sql binding

Tags: python, snowflake-connector

I have written an object to connect and execute my Snowflake queries:

```
class snowflake_conn(object):
    #some other methods...
    
    #execute method
    def execute(self, sql, bindvars=None):
        try:
            if bindvars is None:
                self.cursor.execute(sql)
            else:
                self.cursor.execute(sql, bindvars)
        except Exception:
            raise
```

Then I tried binding the variables:

```
conn.execute("""
with result as (select * from db.schema.tbl where transaction_date >= :1 or delivery_date >= :1)
select * from result
""", (last_month_date,))
```

It keeps giving me error `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`. I followed the binding variables here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#binding-data

I have tried using `?` and adding extra `(last_month_date, last_month_date)` to no avail. Any idea how I could fix this would be much appreciated.

Thank you beforehands.

Edit: added trailing comma in the binding and still same error.

Comment: Typo: `(last_month_date)` => `(last_month_date,)`.

Comment: @ekhumoro I have added the trailing comma and still same error

Comment: Simply use a sequence with enough values for `?`, or a dict with the relevant key/value pairs for `:`. See: [placeholders](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-placeholders).

Comment: @ekhumoro I have mentioned in the original post that I have done that but it didn't work.

Comment: Are sure you actually read the snowflake docs for binding variables? If you're trying to use `qmark` / `numeric` binding, then the syntax is exactly as I stated above. Otherwise, for `pyformat` / `format`, you must use [printf-style string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting). Please re-read the snowflake docs for details on exactly how/when these different formats should be used.

Comment: Hello,

The error message means its expecting string, so please use %s

Example. 

cs.execute("""
    with result as (select * from mycsvtable where seq >= %s )
    select * from result
    """, (last_month_date,) )

Its working fine, please try

Comment: @SujanSghosh Hi yes I figured that out that it expected %s so all is good now. thank you :)